# JMeter SMTP Sampler: Getting Email address is not verified error when sending email

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter. Currently I am trying to send large number of email addresses from my server using SMTP Sampler. My SMTP Sampler is attached in SS.

When I execute my test, it fails and displays "Email address is not verified". The email addresses I am using are valid and no problem is faced when I use gmail server to send emails to it. I am using amazon aws server to send emails.

Any idea why I am getting this **Email address is not verified** error?[image]

Comment: I have tried Use no security features, Use StartTLS in security settings but it shows same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. I was sending from a non-verified email address which was not registered in my AWS SES. Entering a verified email address solved my problem. Thanks to Dmitri again for heads up

Answer (score 1):

Given you use [port `587`](https://www.limilabs.com/blog/ssl-vs-tls-vs-starttls-stls) my expectation is that you should tick `Use StartTLS` radiobutton under "Security settings" section of the [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)

[image: JMeter SMTP Sampler Configuration]

Also make sure that `Address From` matches `Username` as some servers will reject the mail if they are not the same.

Check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Solved my problem. I was sending from a non-verified email address which was not registered in my AWS SES. Entering a verified email address solved my problem. Thanks to Dmitri again for heads up